# Multi-variable non-linear optimization | Convexity and class of problems of form max $\log_{10}\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right)$ under constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, nonlinear-optimization

<sub>Optimization rookie here.</sub>

---

Let function $f : \Bbb R_{>0} \times \Bbb R_{>0} \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$ f(x,y) = \log_{10}\left(\frac{1}{xy}\right) $$

Consider the optimization problem

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x,y}{\text{maximize}} & f(x, y)\\ \text{subject to} & \alpha_1 \leq y\\ & \alpha_2 \leq x\\ & \alpha_3 y \leq x\\ & 3 \log_{10}(x) - \log_{10}(y) < \alpha_4\end{array}$$

where $\alpha_1=0.4; \alpha_2=0.7; \alpha_3=1.33; \alpha_4=0.746$. My question is: is this a convex problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x,y)$ is convex (and $-f(x,y)$ is concave), as can easily be seen by looking at its Hessian. Because $f(x,y)$ is being maximized, this is a non-convex optimization problem. Further, the last constraint is non-convex.

The problem is indeed feasible, and the globally optimal solution is $x=0.7, y=0.4.$ With these input parameter values, this is a trivial problem for any numerical global optimization solver to solve. Given the lower bounds on $x$ and $y$, it is clear that the optimal objective value can't be lower than it is when $x$ and $y$ are at their lower bounds. Because that point also satisfies the last constraint, and is therefote feasible, it must be globally optimal.